# Angular ajax image not updating

Tags: javascript, angularjs, ajax

So I have the following code:

```
<body lang="en-US" ng-app="socket-server" ng-controller="imageValidationController">
    <div class="image-panel">
        <h1>Images Found:</h1>
        <div class="image-list" ng-repeat="image in images">
            <p>Image size: {{image.size}}</p>
            <p>Width: {{image.width}}</p>
            <p>Height: {{image.height}}</p>
            <img class="image" ng-src="{{image.image}}">
        </div>
        <p>Total images found: {{num_images}}</p>
    </div>
```

and I have the following javascript:

```
    var app = angular.module('socket-server', []);


    app.controller('imageValidationController', function($scope, $http) {
        $http({
            method: 'POST',
            data: 'html=<html><body><img src="https://media.giphy.com/media/lhvyCCcFuQFKo/200.gif"></body>',
            url: '/app/image-validation',
            headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
        })
        .then(function(response) {
            $scope.images = response.data.images;
            $scope.num_images = response.data.num_images;
        })

    })
```

/app/image-validation returns an object of the format:

```
{
    images: [ 
        {
            image: 'http://someurl.com/image.jpg',
            size: 471812
            width: 640
            height: 480
        }
    ]
}
```

I've verified that it works.

Everything works fine, the image size, width, height all get updated, however the image does not. It does create an image tag with the correct source, but the image doesn't load at all. I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Comment: show Your `/app/image-validation`s code...

Comment: All you have to know is that it works and it returns a correct response.

Comment: If your data is okay (check Murali's answer) can you make sure that image path actually exist and that you're not hiding images with css or something?

Comment: I figured out what it was, the url in question wasn't really an image, so it wasn't working. It works if I try with another image url. Thanks for the help guys, will leave an answer explaining what happened soon

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Basically the url in the post data, https://media.giphy.com/media/lhvyCCcFuQFKo/200.gif isn't really a gif. it's an html page with the gif in question, so it wasn't loading it.

If I use another image url for the post data it works just fine:

```
app.controller('imageValidationController', function($scope, $http) {
    $http({
        method: 'POST',
        //should work fine now
        data: 'html=<html><body><img src="https://media3.giphy.com/avatars/nikdudukovic/ylDRTR05sy6M.gif"> </body>', 
        url: '/app/image-validation',
        headers: {'Content-Type': 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'}
    })
    .then(function(response) {
        $scope.images = response.data.images;
        $scope.num_images = response.data.num_images;
    })

})
```

returns as data:

```
{
    "images":[
        {
             "image": "https://media3.giphy.com/avatars/nikdudukovic/ylDRTR05sy6M.gif",
             "size": 337783,
             "width": 250,
             "height": 250,

        }
    ],
    "num_images": 1
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The only problem is with the response data. It should be like

**Before:**

```
{
    images: [ 
        {
            image: 'http://someurl.com/image.jpg',
            size: 471812
            width: 640
            height: 480
        }
    ]
}
```

**After:**

```
{
    images: [ 
        {
            image: 'http://someurl.com/image.jpg',
            size: 471812,
            width: 640,
            height: 480
        }
    ]
}
```

Here is a fiddle with the proper response data and it works great!

<kbd>**JSFiddle Demo**</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps it could be as simple as adding a decache query string to the image URL? ie.

```
.then(function(response) {
        $scope.images = response.data.images;
        $scope.num_images = response.data.num_images;

      angular.forEach( $scope.images.image ,  function(url, key) {         
       $scope.images[key].image= url+ '?decache=' + Math.random();
    })
```